# how to aggregate columns based on the value of others

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

If i had a dataframe such as this, how would i create aggragtes such as min,max and mean for each Port for each given year?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Year': {0: 2019, 1: 2019, 2: 2019, 3: 2019, 4:2019},'Port': {0: 'NORTH SHIELDS', 1: 'NORTH SHIELDS'  2: 'NORTH SHIELDS', 3: 'NORTH SHIELDS', 4: 'NORTH SHIELDS'},'Vessel capacity units': {0: 760.5, 1: 760.5, 2: 760.5, 3: 760.5, 4: 760.5},'Engine power': {0: 790.0, 1: 790.0, 2: 790.0, 3: 790.0, 4: 790.0},'Registered tonnage': {0: 516.0, 1: 516.0, 2: 516.0, 3: 516.0, 4: 516.0},'Overall length': {0: 45.0, 1: 45.0, 2: 45.0, 3: 45.0, 4: 45.0},'Value(£)': {0: 2675.81, 1: 62.98, 2: 9.67, 3: 527.02, 4: 2079.0}, 'Landed Weight (tonnes)': {0: 0.978,1: 0.0135, 2: 0.001, 3: 0.3198, 4: 3.832}})

df1
```

Comment: please, provide a sample code with initial data

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The sample data is included in the image

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
df.groupby(['PORT', 'YEAR'])['<WHATEVER COLUMN HERE>'].agg(['count', 'min', 'max', 'mean']) #groupys by 'PORT', 'YEAR' and finds the multiple arguments of count, min, max, and mean
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading. From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Comment: Thanks I'll do that going forward

Answer (score 0):

Without any kind of background information this questions is tricky. Would you want it for every year or just some given years?

To extract min/max/mean etc is quite straightforward. I assume that you have some kind of datafile and have extracted a df from there:

```
file = 'my-data.csv'  # the data file
df = pd.read_csv(file)

VALUE_I_WANT_TO_EXTRAXT = df['Column name']
```

Then for each port you can extract the min/max/mean data like this.

```
for i in range(Port):
    print( i, np.min(VALUE_I_WANT_TO_EXTRAXT) )
```

But, as I said. Without any kind of specifik knowledge about the problem it is hard to provide a solution

Comment: For every year, in this case its the years 2017,2018,2019

Comment: Ok, what min and max would you like to calculate? Vessel capacity units? Enginge power? What have you tried? What part of your code is not working? Please specify. The comment made by @AchAngelPwn is correct though. groupby is probably what you should investigate